# counting documents in category children of Tree-based categories structure

Tags: ruby, count, tree

Ok I have tricky ruby question. 
I have categories and documents where documents below to 1 category. Documents only below to categories at level 2 for example: (please excuse the block quotes)

Cat 1 --> Group 1 --> [Doc 1, Doc 2, Doc 3]

```
  --> Group 2 --> [Doc 4, Doc 5, Doc 6]
```

Cat 2 --> Group 1 --> [Doc 7]

```
  --> Group 2 --> [Doc 8]
```

I have successfully determined the number of documents in each category at the second level (eg. in group 1) with this code:

```
category.associated_docs.count
```

However, how do i find the total number of documents in all the children of the level 1 categories?

I know that i can do the following, but how to I get the sum?

```
category.children.each do |category|
  category.associated_docs.count
```

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the documents are in ActiveRecord, then you may want to do an SQL query to efficiently select all associated docs, then perform count on those.  Otherwise commands involving iteration on arrays of ruby objects could take quite a while.

Else, you may want to try something like the following:

category.children.map{|category| category.associated_docs}.flatten.count

The map commands would return an array containing many sub-arrays, each containing the associated documents for each category.  The flatten commands merges these into a single-level array, from which it is fairly trivial to count them using count.